# How to overlap other elements using resizable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-resizable

How do I keep a resizable div from being overlapped by neighboring elements? I changed the z-index of the resizable div to have 1, and the rest 0.

This example will make it clear right away:
http://jsfiddle.net/gALUP/1/

**HTML**

```
<div id='grid'>
    <div class='outline'>
        <div class='container resizable'>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class='outline'>
        <div class='container'>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outline { 
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black; 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 0; 
    display: inline-block;
}
.container { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.resizable { 
    background-color: #0000ff; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1; 
}
```

Comment: sorry, but it is actually not clear to me, no overlap at all. Are you perhaps working with IE7/IE8? Using inline block in those browsers is a bad idea. better use display: block and float: left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `z-index: 0` from `.outline`:

```
.outline {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.resizable {
    background-color: #0000ff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/gALUP/2/

Comment: So simple. Why does that fix it?

Comment: Because you're setting a lower z-index on the parent so no matter what you set on the children element it'll have no effect